# How long does it take to build cmake on a raspberry pi 3 A+

Tags: make, benchmarking

How long does it take to configure, build and install [CMake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake) on a Raspberry pi 3 A+?

I'm aware that CMake is part of the standard package library, but sometimes you need to build a different, or your own version.

Comment: Not sure if this helps your particular use but you can build on a Pi 3 and it will still work on a Pi Zero - will be much faster to build.

Comment: That's good to know! I have a Pi3 somewhere, I may add benchmarks if I find time.

Comment: Turns out I was actually using a PI3A+, updated question to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently been through this process and wanted to capture the answer for future reference. These benchmarks were taken using a regular stopwatch.

- Configure: `30 minutes`
- Make: `80 minutes`
- Make Install: `1 minutes`

I was building CMake version: 3.13

using the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/Kitware/CMake.git
cd CMake
mkdir build && cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Please accept your answer. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again.